# AWS pcluster fails with MasterServerWaitCondition Received FAILURE signal, iptables and chef version error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create an AMI for parallelcluster. I used amazon's stock AMI (ami-0436692c7b452bae4 for us-west-2, the region I am in, and alinux) and modified it slightly by adding a few packages.

However, when I run `pcluster create foo --norollback` I get the error:

```
Beginning cluster creation for cluster: stockAWS
Creating stack named: parallelcluster-stockAWS
Status: parallelcluster-stockAWS - ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS                         
Cluster creation failed.  Failed events:
  - AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup ComputeFleet Resource creation cancelled
  - AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition MasterServerWaitCondition Received FAILURE signal with UniqueId i-booyaa
```

I then run `ssh foo` and look at the logs in `/var/log/cfncluster-init.log` which shows a long error log, the bottom of which I have provided:

```
2021-07-28 23:16:49,659 [ERROR] Command chef (chef-client --local-mode --config /etc/chef/client.rb --log_level auto --force-formatter --no-color --chef-zero-port 8889 --json-attributes /etc/chef/dna.json --override-runlist aws-parallelcluster::_prep_env) failed
2021-07-28 23:16:49,659 [DEBUG] Command chef output: Starting Chef Client, version 14.2.0
[2021-07-28T23:16:47+00:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2021-07-28T23:16:47+00:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2021-07-28T23:16:47+00:00] WARN: Original Run List: [recipe[aws-parallelcluster::slurm_config]]
[2021-07-28T23:16:47+00:00] WARN: Original Run List: [recipe[aws-parallelcluster::slurm_config]]
[2021-07-28T23:16:47+00:00] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[aws-parallelcluster::_prep_env]]
[2021-07-28T23:16:47+00:00] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[aws-parallelcluster::_prep_env]]
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["aws-parallelcluster::_prep_env"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - aws-parallelcluster (2.5.1)
  - poise-python (1.7.0)
  - tar (2.1.1)
  - selinux (2.1.1)
  - nfs (2.6.4)
  - yum (5.1.0)
  - yum-epel (3.1.0)
  - openssh (2.6.3)
  - apt (7.0.0)
  - hostname (0.4.2)
  - line (2.4.1)
  - ulimit (1.0.0)
  - pyenv (3.1.1)
  - kernel_module (1.1.2)
  - poise (2.8.2)
  - poise-languages (2.1.2)
  - iptables (8.0.0)
  - hostsfile (3.0.1)
  - poise-archive (1.5.0)

Running handlers:
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 11 seconds
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /etc/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /etc/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookChefVersionMismatch: Cookbook 'iptables' version '8.0.0' depends on chef version [">= 15.3"], but the running chef version is 14.2.0
[2021-07-28T23:16:49+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookChefVersionMismatch: Cookbook 'iptables' version '8.0.0' depends on chef version [">= 15.3"], but the running chef version is 14.2.0

2021-07-28 23:16:49,659 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of chefPrepEnv: Command chef failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command chef failed
2021-07-28 23:16:49,661 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
```

If I run `iptables --version` i get `v1.8.4`. same for running it with sudo. chef is `14.2.0`

the frustrating thing is that if i create a parallelcluster stack with the stock aws AMI, I get the exact same behavior. What's going on here?

Comment: The error message says "CookbookChefVersionMismatch: Cookbook 'iptables' version '8.0.0' depends on chef version [">= 15.3"], but the running chef version is 14.2.0"

Comment: @digijay Thanks, I did notice that bit, but `iptables --version` shows v 1.8.4. chef version is 14.2.0. the sudo version of iptables is the same.

Comment: Yes, a version 8.0 of iptabled doesn't even exist, I wonder where that might be defined. Does the cluster start if you leave out the iptables cookbook?